# How to get URL rewrite Target Path programmatically

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, model, index

I need to get programmatically the "Target Path" field that I have set in the Magento 1.8 Admin Panel, using Catalog -> URL rewrite management. How do I get it?

Answer (score 7):

The responsible model is `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite` which has several possible methods to load:

- `$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->loadByRequestPath($path)`
- `$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->loadByIdPath($path)`
  and the usual
- `$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->load($id)`

And then it's a standard attribute getter:

```
$rewrite->getTargetPath()
```

Comment: Thank you friend. Can you let me figure out how to set up the $path variable?

Comment: I have tried that:
$path = $category->getRequestPath();
$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->loadByRequestPath($path);
$tmp = $rewrite->getTargetPath();

$path = $category->getPathId();
$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->loadByIdPath($path);
$tmp = $rewrite->getTargetPath(); 

But I can't get the right value.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you. The code you suggest works fine.
In order to find the redirection target path URL I have found that you have to call the functions in the following sequence:
$path = $category->getRequestPath();
$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->loadByIdPath($path);
$targeturl = $rewrite->getTargetPath();

Because, wath is the request_path before the redirection, become the id_path in the final url_revrite.

Comment: Glad, I could point you in the right direction. In your question you didn't mention that you wanted to find the target path for a given category, so I could not tell you which method is the one you need. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: This all works great.  I wanted to add that in a multi-store setup you'll need to also add the store ID.

Add ->setStoreId( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() ) to your model calls.

Example:

$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setStoreId( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )->loadByRequestPath($path);

$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setStoreId( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )->loadByIdPath($path)

$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setStoreId( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )->load($id)